# The verb for setting upper limits is "cap", what is the verb for setting lower limits?

Tags: word-request

I think "cap" can only be used for setting upper limits but not lower limits, any idea for the verb for setting lower limits?

Example:

The mortgage rate is capped at 3% for three years. <-> The upper limit of the mortgage rate is 3% for three years.

The lower limit of the mortgage rate is 1%. <-> The mortgage rate is [what is the verb?] at 1%.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with lower limits? Do you mean minimums?

Comment: You should write an example using the words in the context you intend.

Comment: I always see the word "cap" used for setting upper limits but, in my opinion, it can be used for setting lower limits too.

Answer (score 3):

**bottom**.

> The cap for the mortgage is 3% and the bottom is 1%.

This counterpart can't be verbed though.

> The mortgage is capped at 3% and <strike>bottomed at 1%</strike>.

You must use *limited at the bottom to* or something similar.

Comment: While I don't doubt the technical accuracy of your answer, I don't think that this usage would be well/widely understood. But that could just be me.

Answer (score 2):

*Capped at X* means "can't go higher than X", which implies X will be subject to increasing in quantity.

*Loss* can be capped (it means the  amount of loss can't be any higher than X), but if something is decreasing in quantity, or not changing in quantity, *capped at X* doesn't work too well.

If the quantity change is variable or negative instead of mostly increasing, *cap* might not be the best word, you probably want to simply say "limited" or use "ceiling" and "floor" to describe the upper and lower limit, respectively.

Comment: Generally, you hear "floor" as the lower limit of something. For example, "the NHL salary cap is set at $80 million and the salary floor is $70 million." Use of ceiling isn't quite as universal.